# How to get list of all users in angular meteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

Am new to meteor development, could you please help me?

I am publishing

```
// server
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
if (this.userId) {
return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
} else {
this.ready();
}
});
```

and on client side how can get the published users data?

Comment: Your code is only publishing the current user, not all users.

Comment: By the way, where's the angular aspect?